# Why is my default password for mysql not empty string

Tags: mysql, linux

I ran this [sudo apt-get install mysql-server] in the terminal and when I logged in as root [mysql -u root -p] the empty space is not my password. According to what I've read the installation should prompt for a password but mine did not pop up yet it still rejected the empty string as password

Comment: did you try just using `mysql -u root`?

Comment: @blissini — I did. That doesn't work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A default install of MySQL on Debian / Ubuntu has password-less access when you are logged on as the **system** root user, but not other times that you log into as the MySQL root user.

You need to become the root user on the system first.

```
sudo su -
mysql
```

Comment: @FlashThunder — Yes. I just tested it to make sure.

Comment: oh sorry didn't understand ... now I get what You mean... thought It would be obvious to login as root mysql user...

Comment: I dont' understand why this was voted down, it absolutely solved my problem